# jQuery slideUp and slideDwon issues

Tags: jquery, slidedown

I need the classes 'two and three' to be hidden as soon as the page load and than be able to click again on the menu to slide it down, I am having probles with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{

$('.two, .three').slideUp('slow');

$('.active_wrapper').click(function(){
    $('.two, .three').slideDown('slow');
});

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="nav_wrapper">

    <div class="active_wrapper one"><a class="active" href="">home</a></div>

    <div class="two"><a href="about.html">about</a></div>

    <div class="three"><a href="project.html">project</a></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GsF5E/)

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{

$('.two, .three').slideUp('slow');

$('.active_wrapper').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.two, .three').slideToggle('slow');
});

});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L6PkX/

use with css display none on .two, .three and remove slideup

```
<div class="nav_wrapper">

    <div class="active_wrapper one"><a class="active" href="#">home</a></div>

    <div class="two"><a href="about.html">about</a></div>

    <div class="three"><a href="project.html">project</a></div>

</div>

$(document).ready(function() 
{


$('.active_wrapper').click(function(){
    $('.two, .three').slideDown('slow');
});

});

.two, .three{
    display: none;
}}
```